How to create Twig extension in Craft CMS 5
I am new to Craft CMS and Yii2 but I'm experienced with PHP a lot.
I'd like to write a custom Twig function (extension) returning a part of a file. For example something like:
{{ craft.myplugin.getFilePart("myfile.txt") }}

There is a documentation for building a module but it's unclear for me:
https://craftcms.com/docs/5.x/extend/module-guide.html
I understand I need to create a PHP file in modules/ folder containing PHP class for it. I also understand the PSR-4 concept for autoloading the class in composer.json.
What events should I bind in init() function? I haven't found any documentation.

There's a page in the docs you might have missed that covers this here:
https://craftcms.com/docs/5.x/extend/extending-twig.html
So specifically, you want to bind the EVENT_INIT event of the Craft Variable instance:
https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v5/craft-web-twig-variables-craftvariable.html#event-init

If you started this project with a Craft 5, you have access to Generator, which can scaffold a Twig extension for you! In the project directory, run:
php craft make module

# ...

php craft make twig-extension --module=<your-module-id>

This will generate the classes and provide all the connective tissue required to expose new Twig filters, functions, and global variables.
Other resources you might be interested in:

Behaviors are used to mount functionality to the native craft variable.
Events are typically how you register new components like Twig extensions.
More info on the Generator tool, mentioned above.
A conversation about different ways to expose functionality to Twig.


 Tip: To generate a behavior, run this:
php craft make behavior


